# Add icon to context menu in quick access

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I have recently been very irritated about the fact that there are no icons in the context menu of folders in the quick access menu. It would make it easier and quicker to differenciate context menu items if I were able to assign icons. And prettier because who doesn't like icons? Does someone know how to do this?

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, right click and click properties, can you see customize tab?
if there is customize tab, click it, and click change icon under file icon.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I'd like to edit the icons IN the context menu (that means right-click menu). As you can see in the image nicely included in the post by @normal-human AMD Catalyst Control Center has such an image. I have found how to edit custom context menu entries that you previously made yourself, but not how to edit system entries that are already present. Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I too want to find this out but have not been able to. I think this is the ONLY way

https://www.quickaccesspopup.com/tag/context-menu/