# how to insert quick access menu into context drop down menu

Tags: context-menu, windows-10-quick-access

I know this question has been asked before
[Add icon to context menu in quick access](https://superuser.com/questions/964948/add-icon-to-context-menu-in-quick-access/1613612#1613612)
but that was 5 years ago.
When I right click anywhere, I want to see an entry which will allow to me to click it and show this...

[image]

Does Windows 10 have that feature anywhere?